# MEAN stack - What is the difference between storing my views in the public folder or the server views folder?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

When doing the front end, I have all my HTML files in public/app/views. I noticed that many people also have a views folder for the server side, for example containing .ejs files. Is that just so they can use a templating engine like Jade? If I am not using a templating engine, can I keep all my views in the public folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to compile the views, you can place them in the public folder.

In fact, it will probably be faster since you don't have to request the rendered view to the server like

```
router.get('/partials/:name', function (req, res){
   var name = req.params.name;
   res.render('partials/' + name);
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you use html for views you can store them in public folder. In other cases (jade or other templating engine) you must convert them to html and copy to public folder, and it's a good idea to use Grunt or Gulp to do this.